# How to query from multiple tables?

Tags: sql

You are given a bank database witht the following schema :

> Customer (Cust_id, Cust_name, Cust_dob, Cust_street, Cust_city);
>
> Account (Account_id, Balance, Type);
>
> Branch(Branch_name, Branch_city, Assets);
>
> Employee(Employee_id,Employee_name,Employee_dob,Employee_street,Employee_startdate);
>
> Loan(Loan_id, Amount);
>
> Borrower(Cust_id,Loan_id);
>
> Depositor(Cust_id,Account_id);
>
> Cust_banker(Customer_id,Employee_id);
>
> Loan_Branch(Loan_id,Branch_name);

Write SQL commands to answer the following queries:

- a) Find only the branches located in 'Horseneck'
- b) Find names and date of birth for all customers with loan greater than 1400.
- c) Find the names of all bracnhes that have accets less than that of all branches located in Brooklyn.
- d) Create a view that displays the Branch Name and their maximum Loan Amount in ascending order of the maximum loan amount of that branch.
- e) Insert a loan account 'L-26' with amount 10000 for customer 'C000000010'.

Comment: What have you tried so far? We don't do your homework here. I can only say you need to use JOIN's

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic first

Answer (score 0):

You can a lot of "functions".

To select who borrowed something, you can use

```
"SELECT loan_id FROM customer JOIN borrower ON customer.cust_id=borrower.cust_id AND cust_name='hocpana';
```

because tabels customer and borrower had a similar word, cust_id.

Hope my words help! :)